# Merging together inline assembly snippets

Tags: c, assembly, x86, mingw, inline-assembly

So, I have this code that works as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    unsigned int i;
    int x=5;

    __asm__ ("movl %1, %0;"
             "subl %2, %0;"
           : "=r" (i)
           : "r" (4), "r" (x)
           : "0");

     __asm__ ("movl %1, %0;"
           : "=r" (x)
           : "r" (i)
           : "0");

    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

How do I merge the two calls into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `__asm__` sets: `i <- 4 - x`. The second sets: `x <- i`. They can be combined as:

```
__asm__ ("subl %k2, %k0" : "=r" (x) : "0" ((unsigned)(4)), "g" (x));
```

No clobbers are needed (unless you want to include `"cc"`, which is always assumed by gcc anyway), and there's no issue of inputs being overwritten before they are read. The `"g"` constraint indicates that a register, memory, or immediate operand is acceptable. The output should be: `"-1"` in this case: `x <- 4 - 5`

Note: the first `__asm__` should have `=&r` for its output. Furthermore, neither should list `%0` as clobbered - this is implicit, as `%0` is an output in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Those are nonsensical asm blocks to start with. Rule of thumb is, if you ever use a `mov` you are probably doing it wrong. Also, even though you claimed it works as expected, the code is broken. Nothing stops the compiler from allocating `%2` to the same register as `%0` producing wrong code. You were just lucky it didn't happen for you.

Anyway, the second asm block simply copies `i` into `x`. As such a merged asm could look like:

```
__asm__ ("movl %2, %0;"
         "subl %3, %0;"
         "movl %0, %1;"
           : "=&r" (i), "=r" (x)
           : "r" (4), "r" (x));
```

This is of course still silly, but at least it isn't technically wrong. Notice the early-clobber `&` modifier for the first output. It isn't needed for the second, however.